# Is it worth to redirect images folder through .htaccess even if changes done in path to show on front end?

Tags: seo, htaccess, images

I am considering to move my images from folder `site/userimages` to subfolder `site/images/userimages`.

The changes will be done in PHP files regarding the path change so that images do continue to show up on the main board of the site, however is it well reqd to show to search engines that the path folder is changed.

I mean as the images will keep on contuing to show on the front end of the page. 
Is it also important to let search engines know that the folder has moved to a subfolder in the site through .htaccess redirect.

Note: the images are well indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL for the images have changed you will need to do a 301 redirect to tell the search engines where their new location is if you wish to preserve their rankings (and all other SEO factors associated with them like links, etc). Images are no different than web pages. They are all documents to the search engines and the same rules apply.